# Writing to csv with 'a' method: headers and new values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm opening a csv file with the append method `'a'` to write a new row as the result of each calling of a function, using `DictWriter` (only writing one new row from each call).

`keys = ['15000', '15001', '15002', '15003']`

`values = [18, 20, 3, 9] ##changes each time function run`

The values change every time I fun the function. The keys generally stay the same but as I am scraping from an XML file more may be added in future (with correlating new values). I'd therefore like to be able to map the values to the fieldnames consistently.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    w = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = keys, lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerheader()
    w.writerow(dict(zip(fnames, values)))
```

The problem here is that each time `writerheader()` writes the header under the previous row. The resultant csv looks like:

```
15000, 15001, 15002, 15003  
18, 20, 3, 9   
15000, 15001, 15002, 15003  
20, 15, 4, 12
```

I'd like this not to have the repeated header. I'm aware that I could start off with a csv with only the initial keys as the header, but this doesn't solve my problem if the dictionary keys change on future function calls. Also, if new keys are added is this going to map values to keys consistently? Will I run into problems?

P.S. note that I added `lineterminated = '\n'` para as the default `DictWriter` method was creating a blank line on each append.

Comment: What is the output that you want to get here? Typically you would use the csv module to read or write an entire file, instead of appending to an existing file.

Comment: The `writeheader()` function will write the headers, that's it's purpose, so no surprise here. You can try to call it only on empty files, that will probably solve the problem with headers. However, adding a column to existing CSV file is not a thing you'd like to do. Why not use SQLite to accumulate data and then export it to CSV?

Comment: Thanks,  I'll look into that. I know that appending current files not the typical approach but always ready to attempt failure! I had though that writeheader () could rewrite the first row of an existing csv file.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you will need to rewrite the whole CSV file whenever the columns change.

If a new column is appended to the existing keys the current data rows will need to have an empty field appended. Or, instead of an empty field, you might have some default value that should be added.

So, you will need to open the existing CSV file with a `DictReader`. Get the `fieldnames` and append the new column(s). Then read each row from the original file, optionally updating the dictionary with a default value for the new column. Then write that to a new file with a `DictWriter` configured with the new `fieldnames`. Finally add your new row(s).

```
import os
import shutil
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def append_csv(csv_filename, data):
    with open(csv_filename, 'a+') as csv_file:
        reader = DictReader(csv_file)
        new_keys = set(data.keys()).difference(reader.fieldnames)
        if not new_keys:
            csv_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            writer = DictWriter(csv_file, reader.fieldnames)
            writer.writerow(data)
        else:
            reader.fieldnames.extend(sorted(new_keys))
            with NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', delete=False) as csv_tmpfile:
                writer = DictWriter(csv_tmpfile, reader.fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerows(row for row in reader)
                writer.writerow(data)
            shutil.move(csv_tmpfile.name, csv_filename)
```

This is going to be very inefficient if the fields change often. Instead you might want to write to a separate CSV file whenever the columns change and then perform a merge at a later time.

Comment: Thanks,  that looks like it might be a bit much in this case, but thanks for the suggestion. As the headings don't change that often I might rely on the manual approach